FTPで誤ってCentOS7から削除したディレクトリを戻す方法について
質問経緯
CentOS7からFTP(FileZilla)で、削除予定ではなかったディレクトリを削除してしまいました。
上書きしてしまったので今回の復活は諦めたのですが、今後のために教えて下さい。
Q1.FTPで削除 ＝＝ CentOSコマンドで削除 ですか？
FTPで削除した場合にも、FTP経由でCentOSコマンドで削除したことになるので、対処方法としては同じですか？
Q2.「telinitコマンド」「extundelete」「TestDisk」の違いは？
検索したら上記 3 つが見つかったのですが、それぞれどう違うのですか？

質問が二つも見えます。質問は一つにしてください。

(今回に限らず) 質問のタイトルに「～について」と付けるのは極力避けてください。端的にやりたいことを説明すべきで、「について」と書いてるとき、大抵は質問内容が精査できていません。参考: 件名に「～ついて」「～の件」と書いてはいけない

telinit は Linux のランレベルを変更するコマンドで、なぜこの質問内容に絡んでくるのか逆に説明を求めたいレベルで無関係です。検索したのならそれぞれどんなコマンドなのかも深堀りしてみてください。

CentOS7 のデフォルトのファイルシステムは XFS とのことなので、ianka/xfs_undelete: An undelete tool for the XFS filesystem が有効かもしれません。

サーバークライアント関係が質問文だけからだと限りなく不明ですが、
- クライアント＝あなたが ftp コマンドを使ったマシン (=Windows 等)
- サーバー＝ ftpd が動作していて、あなたが消したファイルを保持していたマシン = CentOS
であるとして
A1. はい。ファイルを削除するのは、そのファイルシステムを管理している OS というかマシンというか、の仕事です。なので復元作業もそのマシン上で行います。
注：ファイルシステムが格納されている物理・論理装置と、ファイルシステムを管理している OS っつかマシンは別物である場合があります。
iSCSIについて
A2. ファイルを復元するのは extundelete でしょう。 telinit の仕事は全く違います。 TestDisk はよく知らないですが、ちょっと調べた範囲ではパーティションを復元するのが主眼で、ファイルの復元はおまけっぽい感じ。
ですが今時の SSD ではそもそも消したファイルを復元できる可能性は、その昔のハードディスクの時代と比べて激減します。 事実上回復不可能と思ってください。
ext4 で `rm` してしまったファイルやディレクトリが、復旧できるのは何故でしょうか?
んで、こういう誤操作に対しては（あなた自身の質問ですが）
CentOS各種設定ファイルのバックアップについて。どうやってどこへ保存するのですか？
※ Web サーバー httpd で公開している htdocs 配下にこの手のリポジトリを作ってしまうと、昔公開してしまった秘匿データで今は非公開にしたものなんかも、知識と悪意の両方あるユーザーからは見えてしまったりします。その辺は事前に慎重な検討が必要。
